std::print() wrapper with altered format
I try to create a std::print() wrapper with a modified format (e.g. add something before and after the original format).
I can achieve this using a macro:
#define DECORATED_PRINT(fmt, ...) std::println("prefix " fmt " suffix", __VA_ARGS__)

but I would prefer a (template) function, with perfect forwarding, compile time checks and stream locking.
The following works but it is not thread safe (unless I protect it with an additional mutex):
template<typename...Args>
void decoratedPrint(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args){
    std::print("prefix ");
    std::print(fmt, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    std::println(" suffix");
}

Would be possible to have one single call to std::print() with the modified format? something like:
template<typename...Args>
void decoratedPrint(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args){
    std::print("prefix " fmt " suffix", std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}

One idea would be to have a thread_local buffer, write in it in 3 steps (prefix, content, suffix) then pass it to std::print().
Any better alternatives?
https://godbolt.org/z/rEY4Md4YK

decoratedPrint<"format">(args...) or decoratedPrint("format"_c, args...) are possible, but that's silly.

Yes, you have std::runtime_format for that, but it requires C++26:
template<typename...Args>
void decoratedPrint(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args&&... args) {
    auto decoratedFormat = "prefix " + std::string(fmt.get()) + " suffix";
    std::print(
        std::runtime_format(decoratedFormat),
        std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...
    );
}

Demo on gcc trunk

This has no compile time checking.

@康桓瑋 std::format_string still validates the decoratedPrint's arguments. The only possible source of errors is incorrectly modifying the format string inside of it.

Before C++26, if you know which encoding you use, you can do one of vprint_unicode or vprint_nonunicode directly. Kind of surprised there's no direct vprint equivalent (as in vformat).
